# How should I parse this statement about a family of events of polynomial cardinality?

Tags: measure-theory, asymptotics, random-matrices

In Tao's book on random matrix theory, we have Lemma 1.1.3 (see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=L51VAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=family+of+events+of+polynomial+cardinality&source=bl&ots=7VnhMeUj2G&sig=28MUBCWVXh7tVGRLsW1oJlL54ow&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC3f6Cud_TAhWC54MKHSNhCeYQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=family%20of%20events%20of%20polynomial%20cardinality&f=false)), but I'm having trouble parsing exactly what's meant by (for example) "$E_\alpha$ is a family of events of polynomial cardinality."

For fixed $\alpha$ in some index set $I$, it's mentioned on the previous page that the event $E_\alpha$ should depend on some parameter $n$, and $E_\alpha(n)$ has the appropriate asymptotic behavior as defined before the lemma.  But I'm a little confused about what it means to say that the family $\{E_\alpha\}$ has cardinality $O(n^{O(1)})$ here.  At first I thought that maybe we mean that there's a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow 2^I$ such that every $\alpha$ belongs to $f(n)$ for some $n$ and the cardinality of $f(n)$ is $O(n^{O(1)})$, but this seems to be equivalent to $I$ being countable.  So I suspect I'm not reading this correctly.

Maybe we mean that the cardinality of the set $\cup_\alpha \{E(n, \alpha)\}$ is $O(n^{O(1)})$? But this seems like an unnatural thing to consider in this context.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that the cardinality of the family ${E_\alpha}$ can only increase as a polynomial function of the $n$ at which all the ${E_\alpha}$ are taken.

So, intuitively, if you are willing to take a larger $n$, and hence go closer to 1, at the $C_An^{-A}$ rate for all the events in the family, you can take a larger family and still the probability that all the events in the family happen, would be getting closer to 1 at the $C_An^{-A}$ rate.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer! Wasn’t expecting this question to get answered after 6 years of being dormant. 

Comment: @JoshKeneda I had the same question, when I was reading the same text, but later on understood so posted the answer, in case anyone else may have the same question. Thanks for asking the question! :)